# How to, with outlook client, perform reply with a HTML button?

Tags: email, outlook

I'm developing one WPF application with email integration.

The emails generated by application are simply HTML pages like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>  
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="mailto:myemail@mail.com?subject=Approve">Approve</a>
            <a href="mailto:myemail@mail.com?subject=Reject">Reject</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to know how to create one HTML button that can perform  automatically reply with outlook.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML in Outlook is rendered by Word, not IE. Your HTML scripts and buttons will not run inside Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>  
        <div class="actions">
        <button onclick="location.href='mailto:myemail@mail.com?subject=Approve'">Approve</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='mailto:myemail@mail.com?subject=Reject'">Reject</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```